# CSS Flexbox- Too much extra vertical space

Tags: html, css

I'm really new to CSS/programming in general and am trying to build a website logo for a friend as practice. He wants his name justified across the entire header and responsive to the page, and I came up with something that *ALMOST* works perfectly. Here's what I've got:

```
<style>
body {
  background: black;
}

.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 1em;
  color: white;
}

.header {
  border: 1px solid white;
  width:30%;
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
  padding: 5px;

  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  line-height: 0em;
  align-items: center;

}

.header h1{
  flex-direction: row;
  display:flex;

  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: auto;
  align-self: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.header h1 p {
  text-align: center;
/*   background: gray;
 */
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: auto;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 20px;

}

</style>

<div class="container">
<div class="header">
<h1><p>I</p><p>S</p><p>T</p><p>H</p><p>I</p><p>S</p></h1>
<h1><p>T</p><p>O</p><p>T</p><p>A</p><p>L</p><p>L</p><p>Y</p></h1>
<h1><p>I</p><p>N</p><p>S</p><p>A</p><p>N</p><p>E</p><p>?</p></h1>
</div>
</div>
```

So it looks okay, at the moment, and I'm comfortable incorporating it into the rest of the site CSS. The problem I'm having is twofold:

A) I cannot seem to adjust the flexbox properties to eliminate/control all of that empty space. The width is fine but the box is too high, and I'm unsure which combination of properties I need to achieve fine-grained control of the header's height.

B) It has 20 p's in a row at the end. This seems inefficient? I'd like to keep it pure CSS for the moment, so this might be unavoidable, but is there a better way to do this by incorporating another language?

Apologies for any rookie mistakes/StackOverflow faux pas. Infinite apologies if this has already been answered clearly elsewhere.

Comment: ***that empty space*** which empty space? we have many empty spaces here.

Comment: ***The width is fine but the box is too high*** the width of what? also which box? theoretically all the block elements can be seen as boxes

Comment: p should not be wrap in h1

Comment: ... if you turn p into span , then you do not have to deal with the 1em defaut margin .. just saying :)

Comment: King King: By box I mean the border around the flexbox at the top of the page, and by "empty space" I mean the space between the lines of text.

Comment: GCyrillus: Yeah! That makes more sense!